# Command Line Interface (CLI) for SQLDeveloper

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I rely on SQLDeveloper to edit and export a schema. 
It works like a charm, and I can run import with sqlplus. 
I have tried using sqlplus to generate the same schema export, with no result.

I cannot use the Oracle expdp tool, because I need an ASCII file to be able to diff it.

So the only option I have is SQLDeveloper.

I would like to automate the export (data + DDL) with a cron job on a Linux box, but I can't find a way to use SQLDeveloper from a command line to generate the export.

Any clue?

Comment: As far as I know SQL Developer simply uses `dbms_metadata.get_ddl()`. So you should be able to script that using SQL*Plus

Comment: By diff do you mean check for DDL differences (i.e. you can use `dbms_metadata_diff`) or diff the entire lot (in which case the size and log output would be enough combined with the metadata diff would be sufficient)?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

For just the schema side of things you may want checkout [show create table equivalent in oracle sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264584/show-create-table-equivalent-in-oracle-sql) which will get you the SQL source of the DDL.

Are you sure you want an ASCII file for the automated export of an entire DB though? I would be surprised if you really want to diff an entire export of a DB. This [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2008956/163949) may help a little though.

If you really want to get a full data dump plus DDL you will have to write your own script that gets the DDL as described in the first link and then select * and process each result into a sql insert.