# Oracle table(s) data to INSERT statements with JAVA

Tags: java, oracle

How can I get sql inserts from a oracle table with JAVA?
Is there a Oracle API for it?

I need to store it in a file, the result file should have these examples lines:

```
-- INSERTING into TEST
Insert into "TEST" ("CODE","FAMILY","SUB_FAMILY","SEVERITY","STATUS","ANOMALY_DATE","DESCRIPTION",
"COMMENTS","VALUE0","VALUE1","VALUE2","VALUE3","VALUE4","VALUE5","VALUE6","VALUE7","VALUE8",
"VALUE9") values (1,'family1','subFamily11','bad','initial',to_date('0005-11-21','DD/MM/RR'),'someDescription',
'someComment','someValue','someValue','someValue','uselessValue','uselessValue',null,null,null,null,null);
```

the example line was created with the export tool from Oracle SQl developer

Thks.

Comment: So you're trying to retrieve logging information for all the inserts that were performed?

Comment: specify a little more what you're trying to do, your question isn't very clear that way

Answer (score 1):

How crucial is it that you have *insert* statements?  The normal way to transfer data between Oracle databases is to use the DataPump utility.  This comes with a PL/SQL API which can be manipulated programmatically.  I posted a sample set of code for doing that in [another recent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886531/taking-dump-of-tables-in-oracle-10g-using-pl-sql-procedure/1889319#1889319).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Toad for Oracle](http://www.quest.com/toad/toad-for-oracle.aspx). You can save a query as insert statements, spreadsheet, CSV... about anything you can think of.

Answer (score 1):

I would also use Toad, but not sure if it's free.
If really need to do it in Java, you *must* use JDBC and the MetaData of the result set to create your commends.
Here an example, just as an idea - it is NOT complete<sup>*</sup>

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:oci:@DB_ID", "user", "password");
try {
  PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE");
  StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder();
  ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery();
  ResultSetMetaData meta = rset.getMetaData();
  int columns = meta.getColumnCount();
  command.append("INSERT (");
  for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
    if (i > 1) {
      command.append(',');
    }
    command.append(meta.getColumnName(i));
  }
  command.append(") VALUES (");
  int head = command.length();
  while(rset.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
      if (i > 1) {
        command.append(',');
      }
      String value = rset.getString(i);
      if (value != null) {
        command.append('\'');
        command.append(value);
        command.append('\'');
      } else {
        command.append("NULL");
      }
    }
    command.append(")");
    System.out.println(command.toString());
    command.setLength(head);
  }
} finally {
  conn.close();
}
```

<sup>*</sup> *missing error handling, type handling (assumed all data is String),...*

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question looking for a pure java implementation to generate the INSERT statements of a Oracle table. I found [this piece of code](http://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/632/) that may be useful to someone that want to do it using just Java with JDBC without any tool.